# How to animate canvas figure by pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a curved line drawn on a canvas:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(20,100,200,100,200,20);
ctx.stroke();
```

How can I animate this line by pixels? By default, it should disappear. And after appear by pixels.

I tried to do this dynamically using JS, but canvas does not work in this case.

Comment: Gather all the pixel points of the curve in an array and iterate that array to draw the curve pixel-by-pixel.

Comment: Also check out Blindman67's Bezier point finding algorithm on this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637211/drawing-a-curved-line-in-css-or-canvas-and-moving-circle-along-it).