# How do I create curved lines in css without using an image

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to create a website that has multiple curved lines and curved borders see image.

I am using vue and trying to make this look the same for desktop and mobile without have an image unless I have to.

[Example of how screen should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkmLB.png)

[Curved lines examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gaVy.png)

Comment: Well, you could use an HTML canvas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637211/drawing-a-curved-line-in-css-or-canvas-and-moving-circle-along-it#answer-36637788

Comment: Thank you for the quick response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw a curve with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803489/draw-a-curve-with-css)

Comment: For some reason your examples doesn't open here. However I'd encourage you to try using SVG. It's lightweight and scales greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with SVG or with border.

Here is a demo with border.

HTML

```
<div class="curve"></div>
```

CSS

```
.curve {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 5px #000; border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;   
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0; 
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) for more about border parameters